# Why, for R data.tables dt1 & dt2, does dplyr::bind_rows(dt1, dt2)[con2] not yield the expected result, but rbindlist(dt1, dt2)[con2] does?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Can someone please explain what happens in this interactively run `R` code? I'm using `dplyr 1.1.2` and `data.table 1.14.8` on `R 3.6.3` on Ubuntu Linux. Note that only after the line implicitly assigning an index to `dt1` does this discrepancy occur. Why does `dt[cond]` give a different result to `subset(dt, cond)` in this case? And is it just generally "dangerous" to combine `data.table` and `tidyverse` functions in a chain?

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
mydt1 = data.table(year=rep(2017:2018, each=3), month=rep(1:3, times=2))
mydt2 = data.table(year=rep(2016:2017, each=3), month=rep(4:6, times=2))
mydt1[year == 2018]    # this appears to assigns `year` as an index to mydt1 
rbindlist(list(mydt1, mydt2))[year == 2017]
# produces expected output:
#    year month
# 1: 2017     1
# 2: 2017     2
# 3: 2017     3
# 4: 2017     4
# 5: 2017     5
# 6: 2017     6
subset(bind_rows(mydt1, mydt2), year == 2017)
# produces the same output as above
bind_rows(mydt1, mydt2)[year == 2017]
# what happens now?
#    year month
# 1: 2017     1
# 2: 2017     2
# 3: 2017     3
```

Comment: I can't replicate this. The last piece of code gives the same result.

Comment: I can replicate it (linux, R-4.3.2, dplyr-1.1.2, data.table-1.14.8)

Comment: I'm a bit older here on this machine admittedly - R 4.2.1, dplyr_1.0.10, and data.table_1.14.5. Might be a recent issue.

Comment: yes, for some reason just looking at `mydt1[year==2018]` sets an "index" attribute: define `mydt1`, look at `attr(mydt1, "index")` (null), then run `mydt1[year==2018]` and look again at `attr(mydt1, "index")` (now not null). The presence of the index is the problem, removing it with `attr(mydt1, "index") <- NULL` then allows `bind_rows(list(mydt1, mydt2))[year==2017]` to return the expected (correct) response.

Comment: Similarly, look at `indices(mydt1)` before and after `mydt1[year==2018]`.

Comment: recreating a data.table also gets rid of the index: `data.table(bind_rows(mydt1, mydt2))[year==2017]` . Still a nasty feature/bug.

Comment: If you use the R package tidytable instead of dplyr, this problem also goes away (simply because tidytable::bind_rows is just using rbindlist instead of dblyr::bind_rows)

Comment: After the fact, I find https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6676 was posted Feb 2023 (6 months ago).

Comment: @r2evans, ooh, I missed that somehow

Comment: Also: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5587

Comment: This example does show somewhat different behaviours to the bugs, though, since there is no key involved in this case (one can check with `keys(mydt1)` which returns `NULL`).

Comment: Note that `bind_rows(mydt1, mydt2)[, .SD[year == 2017]]` will give the correct expected output as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is ["auto-indexing"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-secondary-indices-and-auto-indexing.html). With `data.table`, there can be only one physical index (i.e., `setkey`), but there can also be secondary indices. As a feature (for faster subetting), whenever a subset is done using strict `==` or `%in%`, a secondary index is created and stored with the object.

With `data.table` objects, when combining tables, the indices are dropped, as one might expect:

```r
indices(mydt1)
# [1] "year"        "year__month"
indices(mydt2)
# NULL
rbindlist(list(mydt1, mydt2)) |>
  indices()
# NULL
rbindlist(list(mydt2, mydt1)) |>
  indices()
# NULL
```

But with `dplyr_1.1.2` (at least, not sure if/when things changed), it is preserving attributes of the first table.

```r
bind_rows(mydt1, mydt2) |>
  indices()
# [1] "year"        "year__month"
bind_rows(mydt2, mydt1) |>
  indices()
# NULL
```

This latter discovery suggests that we can get the desired results by reversing the tables:

```r
bind_rows(mydt1, mydt2)[year == 2017]
#     year month
#    <int> <int>
# 1:  2017     1
# 2:  2017     2
# 3:  2017     3
bind_rows(mydt2, mydt1)[year == 2017]
#     year month
#    <int> <int>
# 1:  2017     4
# 2:  2017     5
# 3:  2017     6
# 4:  2017     1
# 5:  2017     2
# 6:  2017     3
```

From the documentation (same link above), we can set the `"datatable.use.index"` option to prevent this behavior. In a new R session (since I didn't want to spoil things):

```r
options(datatable.use.index = FALSE)
mydt1 = data.table(year=rep(2017:2018, each=3), month=rep(1:3, times=2))
mydt2 = data.table(year=rep(2016:2017, each=3), month=rep(4:6, times=2))
mydt1[year == 2018]
#     year month
#    <int> <int>
# 1:  2018     1
# 2:  2018     2
# 3:  2018     3
indices(mydt1)
# NULL
bind_rows(mydt1, mydt2)[year == 2017]
#     year month
#    <int> <int>
# 1:  2017     1
# 2:  2017     2
# 3:  2017     3
# 4:  2017     4
# 5:  2017     5
# 6:  2017     6
```

So my guess is that this is not a "bug" in either `dplyr` or `data.table`, but it sure would be nice if `dplyr` "knew" about this secondary index and chose to not pass this one through when it row-binds them together.

Comment: Very useful; why does having the index set prevent subsetting with `dt[cond]` from providing the correct answer, but not `subset(dt, cond)`?

Comment: Because only `data.table`-tools use the index, otherwise it's just an attribute to ignore. (Realize that `[cond]` is using `\`[.data.table\``, not the traditional `[` primitive.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but if you use `subset(dt, cond)`, does that not use the `subset.data.table` function? And once the index is applied, how does that determine which subset is selected?

Comment: _I have no idea_, that's a great question. It appears to be an omission in the implementation of `subset`?

Comment: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/88039186915028ab3c93ccfd8e22c0d1c3534b1a/R/data.table.R#L2315 it doesn't use [ therefore doesn't benefit any optimizations

Comment: Thanks for weighing in, @jangorecki! I appreciate the backfill.